# how to fetch firebase data?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to python and firebase and I am trying to flaten my firebase database.

I have a database in this format

[image]

each cat has thousands of data in it. All I want is to fetch the cat names and put them in an array. for example I want the output to be ['cat1','cat2'....]

I was using this tutorial 
http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/Data', None)
```

the problem with the above code is it'll attempt to fetch all the data under Data. How can I only fetch the "cats"?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the values inside the cats as columns, try using the [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), using `pip install pyrebase` at `cmd` / `anaconda prompt`(later prefered if you didn't set up PIP or Python at your environment paths. after installing:

```
import pyrebase

config {"apiKey": yourapikey
"authDomain": yourapidomain
"databaseURL": yourdatabaseurl,  
"storageBucket": yourstoragebucket,  
"serviceAccount": yourserviceaccount
}
```

**Note:** you can find all the information above at your Firebase's console:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/   >>> your project >>> click on the icon "<'/>" with the tag "add firebase to your web app

back to the code...

make a neat definition so you can store it into a py file:

```
def connect_firebase():
# add a way to encrypt those, I'm a starter myself and don't know how
username: "usernameyoucreatedatfirebase"
password: "passwordforaboveuser"

    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
    auth = firebase.auth() 

    #authenticate a user > descobrir como não deixar hardcoded
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(username, password)

    #user['idToken']
    # At pyrebase's git the author said the token expires every 1 hour, so it's needed to refresh it
    user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])

    #set database
    db = firebase.database()

    return db
```

Ok, now save this into a neat `.py` file

NEXT, at your new notebook or main .py you're going to import **this new .py file that we'll call** `auth.py` from now on...

```
from auth import *

# add do a variable
db = connect_firebase()

#and now the hard/ easy part that took me a while to figure out:
# notice the value inside the .child, it should be the parent name with all the cats keys
values = db.child('cats').get()

# adding all to a dataframe you'll need to use the .val()  
data = pd.DataFrame(values.val())
```

and thats it, `print(data.head())` to check if the values / columns are where they're expected to be.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database is [one big JSON tree](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data):

> when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve
>   all of its child nodes.

The best practice is to [denormalize your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout), creating multiple locations (nodes) for the  same data:

> Many times you can denormalize the data by using a query to retrieve a
>   subset of the data

In your case, you may create a second node named "categories" where you list "only" the category names.

```
/cat1
    /...
/cat2
    /...
/cat3
    /...
/cat4
    /...
/categories
   /cat1
   /cat2
   /cat3
   /cat4
```

In this scenario you can use the [update() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) to write to more than one  location at the same time.

Comment: thats exactly what I am trying to do. I have hundreds of categories so I want to retrieve them programmatically and create a category node for them

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) documentation. As per that, we may extract only keys from some path.

> To return just the keys at a particular path use the shallow() method.

```
all_user_ids = db.child("users").shallow().get()
```

In your case, it'll be something like:

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

allCats = db.child("data").shallow().get()
```

Let me know if it didn't help.